# Xft:cannot enable font hinting

Tags: arch-linux, rxvt, fontconfig, xft

I cannot enable font hinting in programs which (as far as I understand) do not use the global fontconfig settings.

I first thought it was related only to urxvt.

```
urxvt -fn "xft:Consolas:pixelsize=15:hinting=true:hintstyle=hintfull:antialias=true"
```

or `grep hint .Xresources`

```
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
URxvt.font:     xft:Consolas:pixelsize=15:hinting=true:hintstyle=hintfull:antialias=true
```

There is no hinting. But in experimenting with other terminals such as xterm or st, they also have the same issue of ignoring the hinting.

Similar to another question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321857/why-is-xft-ignoring-font-settings), I can also use pango-view:

```
$ export FC_DEBUG=1

$ pango-view --hinting=full --backend=xft --font=Consolas -t 'Hello world' | grep hint
    hintstyle: 3(i)(w)
    hinting: True(s)

$ pango-view --hinting=none --backend=xft --font=Consolas -t 'Hello world' | grep hint
    hintstyle: 3(i)(w)
    hinting: False(s)
```

Despite the debug message with hinting True/False difference, there is absolutely no difference at all in the font rendering: Both render as `hinting=none`. However, with option `--backend=cairo`, then the hinting takes place and there is a noticeable difference in the rendered fonts.

I've tried `hintfull`, `hintmedium`, `hintslight` – none have any effect.

My story is that I have in fact used urxvt with hinting for a few years. I'd been using this "infinality" freetype patch and configuration, but this now no longer works. So, I'm now using the default freetype (version 2.9-2) package provided by Arch Linux.

The only configuration I did is to enable hinting in the global configuration as follows:

```
~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf

<match target="font">
  <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
    <const>hintmedium</const>
  </edit>
</match>
```

This successfully applies hinting for all programs except urxvt and friends. (One irregularity here is that I used `hintmedium` here instead of `hintfull` – for unknown reasons, inside fonts.conf `hintfull` has no effect whatsoever and is the same as `hintnone`)

So, any ideas on why hinting might not be working for urxvt or st?

Comment: I'll quickly mention that I gave up on this some time ago. I switched to the alacritty terminal, which has none of the above problems.